# ¿Como pintar una tabla con OPTION y que al dar clic en el botón enviar se recupere en JS el valor del OPTION para cada fila obtenida de la query?

Tags: php, html, sql

El problema es que mi consulta da como resultado 20 filas, esos datos los tengo que imprimir y a cada fila debo agregar un OPTION, para después almacenar en mi BD relacionando cada OPTION con el alumno. ¿como hago para darle un identificador a cada OPTION teniendo N alumnos?

```
                            $filas2 = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                            if($filas2>0){
                                    while($row2 = $query->fetch_array())
                                    {
                                        echo "<tr><td>".$row2['grupo']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['matricula']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['nombre']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['apellido_p']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['apellido_m']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['nom_campus']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['dia']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['nivel_mod']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['horario']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td>".$row2['tel']."</td>";

                            ?>
                    <td>
                        <select name="hw1" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Entrego</option>
                            <option value="0">No Entrego</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                      <?php 
                         echo "</tr>";
                              } 
                           } else {
                                echo "no hay registros";
                              }
                    ?>´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de renderizar el `option` puedes aplicar para el `value` un patrón identificador por ejemeplo **IDALUMNO___VALORSELECT** así cuando se envié el form te llegará el valor personalizado que le haz dado al option y sabrás que alumno elegió que opción.

Después simplemente haces un `explode` del patron que haz definido anteriormente para separar los datos y estos te quedarán en un array.

Ejemplo:

```
$value_option_from_form = 'IDALUMNO___VALORSELECT';
print_r(explode('___', $value_option_from_form));
```